# Cannot get the string from char**

Tags: c

I got a program here using double char pointer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void loadarray(char ** message)
{
    int size = 10;
    *message = (char*)malloc(size * sizeof(char));
    int i = 0;
    char stringarr[10]={"hello"};
    char msg_byte;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        //load stringarr into msg_byte
        msg_byte = stringarr[i];
        char* pmsg      = *message;
        *pmsg = (char)msg_byte;
        printf("data location %d is %X\n", i, *pmsg);
        pmsg++;

    }
}


void main()
{
    char* arr;
    loadarray(&arr);
    printf("array = %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X\n", arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], arr[4]);
}
```

**The output I have is**

```
data location 0 is 68
data location 1 is 65
data location 2 is 6C
data location 3 is 6C
data location 4 is 6F
data location 5 is 0
data location 6 is 0
data location 7 is 0
data location 8 is 0
data location 9 is 0
array = 00 00 00 00 00
```

For some reason I can't just pass the string back to main. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help first.

Comment: Daily reminder not to cast the return type of malloc.

Comment: thanks for the reminder. I always thought I have to.

Comment: Daily reminder to back up daily reminders with sources.

Comment: @LinusKleen Daily reminder to look one of the [most famous SO questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Your loop logic is wrong. You keep writing to the same location on every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

```
char* pmsg = *message;
```

You are initializing `pmsg` on each iteration and therefore it always points to the first char, put it before the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have:

```
    char* pmsg      = *message;
```

in the loop. `pmsg` only ever points to the first object of `*message`.

Change the function `loadarray` so that `pmsg` is initialized before the `for` loop.

```
void loadarray(char ** message)
{
    int size = 10;
    *message = malloc(size * sizeof(char));
    int i = 0;
    char stringarr[10]={"hello"};
    char msg_byte;

    char* pmsg      = *message;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        //load stringarr into msg_byte
        msg_byte = stringarr[i];
        *pmsg = (char)msg_byte;
        printf("data location %d is %X\n", i, *pmsg);
        pmsg++;

    }
}
```